# how Font and text rendering is done in different OSes

Tags: text, fonts, rendering

How font rendering is done in linux, bsd, windows? how they differ?

I am not talking about browser web font rendering.say for example how input system works? I press mouse keys. they trigger evdev drivers of linux kernel, and the kernel manages the higher level ops.

low level font rendering mechanism. how freetype, pango, window manager, interact with each other. another big question? how unicode support is accomplished??

simply, when I type a character in a text editor, what are the paths does the character flow before coming into the screen. how the MS word or LibreOffice render different fonts together in single canvas??

Comment: pretty sure this isn't the place for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *nix text-rendering is done client-side nowadays which means apps use whatever lib they like best to transform unicode codepoints to pixels and feed the result to x. The actual libs used wary widely though people has been converging on fontconfig + freetype + freebidi + harfbuzz in the past years, usually accessed through pango-cairo

A summary was posted here a few years ago
http://behdad.org/text/

It's all a devilishly complex process, you have weeks of reading if you want to understand all the steps involved.

[text-rendering](/questions/tagged/text-rendering) [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [fonts](/questions/tagged/fonts)